# Differences in methods for adding middleware for Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I usually use the following code for managing routes on the server:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
    route: '...',
    handle: function(req, res, next) {...},
});
```

However, I've seen another pattern in some places:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```

What are the differences between them, other than syntax and route management? Is one of them better to use due to performance or other reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the middleware works is using a sort of list then handling responses. So if you have

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```

If you don't end with a response here, it will call `next()` and find the next connect handler in the stack to run and if that doesn't have anything the next and so on.

There is a bit of an order to this so the the first method you describe adds something to the beginning of the stack (or the index specified in splice) and the second one adds it to the end of the stack.

So in Meteor it depends on the other middleware, if you want to get access to the `req` & `res` values before the other handlers you could use the first (e.g some kind of HTTP Login check/Upgrading a websocket request) and the other with `.use` for something else at the end of the stack (IP address/cookie checking)

One thing to note though, while I'm not 100% sure about this Meteor might be using middleware too so you need to get to the stack before meteor does so the first syntax might be better especially if meteor ends with a request so the ones added at the end might not have an effect.